# How to resize the header text in jQuery Mobile collapsible?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

the header text format in collapsible content in jQuery mobile is using `<h3>` but It's too big for me. So I want to resize default text size in jquery mobile collapsible.

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
        <h3>My Header</h3>
</div>
```

how to resize it? Thanks :)

here is my simulation >> http://jsfiddle.net/sevtiandy/seXmc/73/

Answer (score 2):

I solve it. I change the file `jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css` and change the `font-size` value from 16px to 13px in class `.ui-collapsible-heading`

Comment: Rather than change the jquery style sheet directly; you should override the style in your custom.css and include that in your app.

Comment: @NirmalPatel but is that possible to get duplicate class in different css files?

Comment: @NirmalPatel that's what I afraid :)

Comment: When you override a CSS class (with same name) only the properties you define in your newer class will be overridden... the rest from the older class will still be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class with the h3 element :

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3 class="collapse_header">My Header</h3>
</div>
```

And using your custom CSS resize it:

```
.collapse_header .ui-btn-text{
    font-size: 10px
}
```